# Preflight request is successful but actual request is throwing an error CORS Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express, cors, ngrok

Im developing a backend using Node.js and express. I am getting the error: "[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/116t8.png)". When I enter the network tab i see that the preflight request of chrome was successful and got all the headers i set on the backend. But the actual request isnt successful and got no headers i set on the backend. Also when i make a POST request its successful, but when i make a get that problem appears.
That's a school project so I had to put it online. I'm using github pages to the frontend and ngrok to run the backend.

[PREFLIGHT REQUEST IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzKin.png)
[ACTUAL REQUEST IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epx2Y.png)

CORS config:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');

    next();
});
```

Request im making and getting problems:

```
    fetch('https://causal-scorpion-rapidly.ngrok-free.app/api/classes?teacherId=own', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('authorization')
        }
    })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) return res.json();
            if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
                ...
            }
            throw new Error(res);
        })
        .then(response => {
            ...
        })
```

Request im making and not getting any problems:

```
fetch('https://causal-scorpion-rapidly.ngrok-free.app/api/classes', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('authorization')
        },
        body
    })
        .then(res => {
            ...
        })
        .then(response => {
            ...
        })
}
```

Also, in ngrok I see that the preflight request was successful handled, but I don't even receive the actual request.
How can i solve that CORS problem?
I've tried using the cors node module but nothing changed.

EDIT:
I solved my problem by adding the header 'ngrok-skip-browser-warning': 'true' to my requests

Comment: Do you define the GET route before or after `app.use(corsmiddleware)` ? If it's before (ie above) your get request will never reach the cors middleware, because routes and middlewares are matched in order of definition

Comment: BTW defining a `content-type` header on a GET request doesn't make to much sense, because you are not sending a body. It might even do some harm, if a greedy middleware at the backend tries to read a non-existent body ...

Comment: The request screenshot looks like it's working.   You get a 200 response back. Why do you say it isn't working?